# How to find the eigenvectors when complex numbers come in?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

When I compute the eigenvalues of A let $e$ donate the eigenvalues

$$e_1=i\\
e_2=-i$$

when i put the $e_1$ in the matrix

$$A-e_1I=\begin{bmatrix}
-i & -1 \\
1 & -i 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So I need to find the nullspace of this matrix right? I go on with it.
$$A-e_1I=\begin{bmatrix}
-i & -1 \\
1 & -i 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}$$

From here

$$-ix-y=0\\
x-iy=0\\$$

I couldn't think of how to solve in this situation. I always encounter the same problem, whenever eigenvalue becomes some complex number I can't compute it's eigenvectors,

Also may I ask can i go to the Upper triangular form in a matrix which has complex numbers in its $a_{ij}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small mistake in your first equation, it supposed to be: $$-ix -y = 0  $$

from here you get $y = -ix $

so $span(1,-i) $ is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue -i.

You could take (1,-i) as an eigenvector.

Also, note that if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of A than $ker(A-\lambda) $ is not trivial - so for sure one of your two equations is spare.

Comment: This is more likely a typo then a confusion, since the OP got the second equation correct.

Comment: It also could be a mistake which led him to think that there is no solution, i changed my answer anyhow. @ArcticChar

Comment: I see your method there.

Comment: But wouldn't $y$ would be a dependent variable as much as x is. Since isn't  the rank of the matrix is two in this case. Both pivots are avaible. Two dependent variables would make $x=y=0$ right? I didnt get that part.

Comment: Or can i multiply the first row with complex numbers so that no pivot is left/ eigenvector is your answer.

Comment: for example, try adding to row 1 irow2 ( i mean R1 = R1 + iR2) , you will see than that you are left with one equation only.  @Xenidia